# for loop not executing the code when a condition is meet

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, for-loop

I have previously asked a question about how can I write a code block in a shorter way, I got my answer and I started adapting it to my circumstances. But I ran into a small problem, here is the code I'm running :

```
var default_cluster_options = {
    limits : [ { min: 1224, items: 8 }, { min: 954, items: 6 }, { min: 624, items: 4 }, { min: 0, items: 2 } ]
};

var default_plugin_options = {
    containerID : "",
    first       : false,
    previous    : false,
    next        : false,
    last        : false,
    startPage   : 1,
    perPage     : 1,
    midRange    : 6,
    startRange  : 1,
    endRange    : 1,
    keyBrowse   : false,
    scrollBrowse: false,
    pause       : 0,
    clickStop   : true,
    delay       : 50,
    direction   : "auto",
    animation   : "fadeIn",
    links       : "title",
    fallback    : 1000,
    minHeight   : true,
    callback    : function(pages, items) {}
};

var Cluster = function(cluster_options, plugin_options) {
    this.options = $.extend({}, default_cluster_options, cluster_options);
    this.plugin_options = $.extend({}, default_plugin_options, plugin_options);
    this.limits = this.options.limits;
    this.inititate_shop();
};

Cluster.prototype.initiate_plugin = function(plugin_navigation, plugin_options) {
    var options = $.extend({}, this.plugin_options, plugin_options);
    return $(plugin_navigation).jPages(options);
};

Cluster.prototype.inititate_shop = function() {
    for (var i = 0; this.viewport_width <= this.limits[i].min; i++) {
        log(this.limits[i].min);
        log(this.viewport_width);
        this.initiate_plugin('.shop-items-navigation', {
            containerID : "shop-items-wrapper",
            perPage     : this.limits[i].items,
            midRange    : 8,
            animation   : "fadeIn",
            links       : "blank",
            keyBrowse   : true,
            callback    : function(pages) {
                log(pages.current);
            }
        });
    }
};

var cluster = new Cluster();
```

Some of the code in there might not make sense because there are other code blocks, but I think that's all the code related to my problem that may cause issues.

And my problem would be the `for()` loop inside the `Cluster.prototype.inititate_shop` property. I see no error in the console but when I tried to see if another loop works on the `this.limits` variable ( which is an array of 4 objects ) it did.

So that's why I don't see why the function won't work or the `for()` loop would break and I'm asking here if anyone spots something I don't ( I have a history of missing things ).

Comment: Have you tested the condition - what are the values of viewport_width and this.limits[i].min?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `this.viewport_width` is the width of the window. The limits are set in that array, inside the object. And yes, I have tested it but nothing happened.

Comment: what's the value of this.viewport_width - the number?

Comment: in my case in full width of the screen 1366px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above - the problem is that your highest min value in the limits list is 1224 but your viewport width is 1366 so:

```
this.viewport_width <= this.limits[i].min;
```

never evaluates to true and the code in the for loop is never executed.

**EDIT 2**

What about if you break out the statement that does the check:

```
Cluster.prototype.inititate_shop = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < this.limits.length; i++) {
    if (this.viewport_width >= this.limits[i].min){
        log(this.limits[i].min);
        log(this.viewport_width);
        this.initiate_plugin('.shop-items-navigation', {
            containerID : "shop-items-wrapper",
            perPage     : this.limits[i].items,
            midRange    : 8,
            animation   : "fadeIn",
            links       : "blank",
            keyBrowse   : true,
            callback    : function(pages) {
                log(pages.current);
            }
        });
        return false; // to break out of loop
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: OK, but how can that be fixed, because that may happen more often than having a small device like 980px wide. Is there a workaround for that ?

Comment: Yes, my first thought was that, but it is a bit weird :) Some suggestion on how to rewrite the logic ? I like the idea of looping through an array or object rather than having an `if() ... else if()` statement :)

Comment: Change the direction of the comparison so that, rather than looking for portal widths less than min, you search for larger values so the final entry in your limits array is then the default situation

Comment: So, using this logic `for (var i = 3; this.viewport_width >= this.limits[i].min; i--)` would fix it ? Or it doesn't add up for all the situations ?

Comment: I've tested the logic @Dave, but it's wrong :)) ( no wonder ). How would that logic look ? Because I cannot think of anything right now that would work, besides the first suggestion with having a big value :)

Comment: Indeed :) It should work, and it does, but yet again, having another size, smaller, like smaller than 1224 breaks the loop again :) So I'm again where I was once before but in the reverse order :) I'll try looking at a better logic to handle that, but if you have time to look over it I would appreciate it :)

Comment: It just stops working, I mean the plugin is not applied anymore. In the situation of having a big value above 1224px, the plugin is applied, but when I resize the window and refresh the page, the plugin it's not applied anymore because I have a smaller than 1224px width value.

Comment: You can view it in action here : http://rolandgroza.com/projects/roland/ . I'm just uploading the contents of what I'm working on, it should work. Just go to the Shop page and there is where the plugin should be applied.

Comment: Well, take a look at the site and see in the console, but until now there is no obvious error or bug. Of course there might be, but I don't see it.

Comment: That's because the plugin fits them right :) Just refresh the browser while on a smaller size :) You'll see that it won't work

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, I haven't explained it right I think. The plugin doesn't work, it only seems so. When you're on the Shop page, and at the width bigger than 1224px, refresh the page. Use the left and right arrows of your keyboard, and you'll see that you can browse through the items, there are about 26 items I think. Well, when you have the window at a size smaller than 1224px, refresh again the page while on the Shop page and try now to use the keys on the keyboard, nothing happens and the items overlap the height ( they get under the footer ). That's because the plugin isn't applied

Comment: I think we're getting outside of my area of knowledge here but I'll try and reason it out; if the plugin loaded in the first place with a large screen size, can you identify anything that unloads the plugin on resize - are there any other events bound? Obviously a resize doesn't cause a postback normally so I think the problem isn't that the plugin hasn't initialised but that, for some reason, it fails to work for a very small window. Are you supposed to reinitialize the plugin on resize - the code you've posted doesn't appear to do this?

Comment: Indeed, it's not supposed to. I only have the code to detect the viewport size and adjust the items / page accordingly, if the screensize is bigger than 1224px I have 8/page, if between 1224px and 954px 6/page, if between 954px and 644px 4/page and if less than 644px 2/page. That's all. So the plugin acts on it's own when resizing but it just pushes down the extra items that overlap the width. So I only acted on the screensize when you land on the page ( no resizing events ). That's why I think it's the logic. because it only initiates the plugin on 1224px and above, if less it doesn't.

Comment: I think this works to, as suggested by another user : `for (var i = 0; this.viewport_width <= this.limits[i].min; i++);` and then having the rest of the code block ( the plugin initiation ) as a separate block. That way, only the `i` value is set for further use. I'll try your suggestion again to see the result.

Comment: Yes @Dave, that makes it work too :) I'm not sure which one is faster though, but I like it because it's nested :) I appreciate the help and sorry if I disturbed you

Comment: Excellent - glad to have helped!

Comment: Could these comments be purged?